# LaserScans not in the Map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, laser-filters, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a node that returns all of the LaserScan points that are (probably) not in the map?

**Edit:** Clarification: I was assuming a static map relative to a robot that has already been localized. What I'd like to be able to say is "these laser scans are of the wall (which has always been there) and this person shaped blob of laser readings is new."

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12411/laserscans-not-in-the-map/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-12-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-12-21**:
Clarification posted above.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-20**:
Could you add some detail to this question? What map (local or global from costmap_2d with s standard nav_stack config? or something entirely different?)? And do you mean the points there are to be inserted into a map as fresh obstacles or a "scan" representing things your scan missed in the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For future users who stumble upon this question, I've written a node (not yet pushed to our public repository) that does this task.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0